# Get lines from stdout after timestamp

Tags: python, regex, shell, logging, stdout

There is a huge log of errors/warnings/infos printed out on stdout. I am only interested in the lines logged after I start a specific action.

Other information: I am using Python to telnet to a shell environment. I execute the commands on shell and store the time the action is started. I then call a command to view the log which spits it on stdout. I expect to read in the greped lines after that timestamp back to Python. I also store the current time but not sure how to use that (maybe grep on a date range?)

I can redirect to a file and use find but the log is huge and I'd rather not read all of it.
I can grep -n to get line number and then read everything after but I'm not sure how to.

Concept regex to egrep on is something like: {a-timestamp}*

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You can record the size of the log file at the time of the action. Then in Python use [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to start reading the log file at the offset corresponding to that size.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for stdout? (that's where the log is dumped)

Comment: What do you mean by "open a log" in your question? Is that not a log file? Is that a pipe?

Comment: Just found a solution:
1) "wc -l" to get number of lines
2) "grep -n {the-timestamp-i-have}" to get the line number i want to start at
3) subtract these and "tail --{difference}

Anything better?

Comment: That looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/the-timestamp-I-have/,0' the-log-file
```

This will print the lines from `the-log-file`, starting at the first line that matches `the-timestamp-I-have` and continuing through the last line.

Ref:

- http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-three/
- http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/#awk_ranges